# ajax with jquery mobile and python templates (using Flask/jinja2)

Tags: ajax, templates, jquery, jquery-mobile, jinja2

I have an HTML page generated from a jinja2 template, and I would like to swap out some of the content using AJAX; however, when I do so the swapped content looks plain and unformatted.

On inspecting the HTML it appears that jQuery Mobile modifies the HTML generated by the jinja2 template quite a bit when the page first loads. When I do my AJAX request, however, jQuery Mobile doesn't do anything to the content and the template is rendered verbatim. How do I get jQuery Mobile to process my HTML from the XHR as if it were a new page load?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to select the element that you are injecting into your jQuery Mobile page, and then call `.page()` on it. i.e.:

```
$('#new_html').page();
```